# Check postMessage on Chrome inspect element

Tags: javascript

I am doing some testing on cross domain comunication, i would want to do the testing directly into chrome inspection rather than keep deploying my script to dev environment. Assuming  have only 2 page ,

localhost:8766 and localhost:8765 
localhost8765 is where i have declared to PostMessage
localhost8766 is the receiver

On Chrome browser , i have selected : devtableau.html as per below image where displaying the message is declared.
[image]

This is working perfectly fine but what im trying to achieve is to declare the `window.addeventlistener` directly to chrome inspect element to do some testing

when i place window.addevenlistener directly to chrome ,  its returning undefined ,

[image]

What is the correct approach in doing this ?